# Find the value of a such that v is the solution space of A

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
How do I do question d)? I got the other ones.

I have also reduced the matrix and I got this
[image]

Where can I go from here? Hints would be great!

Comment: "*...such that v is* **in** *the solution space of $A$*"  You forgot the word "in."  The single vector by itself isn't the entire solution space, but rather it is just one among many vectors in the solution space.  As for how to proceed, ask yourself what it *means* to be in the solution space.  I assume that this is just alternate phrasing of "being in the kernel" or "nullspace" of the matrix., so $Av=0$.  To be in the nullspace, your reduced matrix implies that the third entry of the vector must be equal to ____ times the fourth entry plus ____ times the fifth entry (*letting you fill in*)

Comment: Alternatively, if you couldn't think of how to use your reduced matrix to find any quick and useful information, you could always have multiplied out with $a$ as a variable to see that [$Av=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\54-6a\\27-3a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C3%2C0%2C-3%2C1%7D%2C%7B3%2C9%2C-6%2C15%2C-15%7D%2C%7B-3%2C-9%2C-3%2C21%2C-12%7D%7D*%7B%7B5%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C%7Ba%7D%2C%7B3%7D%2C%7B1%7D%7D) and finished from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you reduced $A$ to 
$$A_r = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 & -3 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $A_rv = 0$, the second row gives you that $$a - 12 + 3 = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

The "solution space" is a waroed term for the kernel or null space of $A$, so multiply $A$ by $v$ and note the first row is $0$ regardless of $a$ (it gets multiplied by $0$ there) but the second equation gives (in your reduced form which has the same "solution space" as $A$ has) :

$$a - 4 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 1 =0$$ (it should be $0$ to get the $0$-vector)

or $a - 9 = 0$ and that should be trivial.

Check with the final equation of the original $A$:

is $$ (-3)\cdot 5 +  (-9) \cdot 1 +  -3\cdot a + 21 \cdot 3 +  (-12) \cdot 1= 0$$

in that case? (it does...)